# audio or speech compression and decompression techniques using MATLAB code

Tags: matlab

i need MAT-LAB code for compression and decompression of audio or speech signals ...help me out by providing the code...and the compression and decompression should be the loss less techiques

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be helpful ,they could suggest you the approach
http://www.lukedodd.com/really-simple-audio-compression/
http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/Multimedia_CM0340/PDF/09_CM0340_Basic_Compression_Algorithms.pdf

Comment: cool abinav...just like dct we got a lot more codecs,,used in voIP such as silk for skype,speex,siren,monkeys audio..once see the link we can imorove the solution http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_codecs